# Native crash on Android 4.3 starting activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, start-activity

Grettings.

I'm building a plugin for my project in unity3d 3.5.7. I'm using eclipse and the library seems to work fine on androids lower than 4.3. However when I run it on 4.3 it crashes creating an activity.

Currently I'm running an activity that extends the UnityPlayerActivity. It starts with no problem. Then I get the current activity on unity and call a method to start another activity. When I create the intent I pass the current context (the activity running) to it. The context at that time is not null. Then I call context.startActivity() and pass the intent that I created. The app proceeds to crash. What is weird is that it works perfect on other version than 4.3.

The logcat crash that I get is this one:

```
    F/libc    (21032): bionic/libc/upstream-netbsd/libc/stdlib/bsearch.c:70: bsearch: assertion "key != NULL" failed
    F/libc    (21032): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 21057 (UnityMain)
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and a workarround to it?

Answer (score 1):

"Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)" - Mostly, this error occurs at native side when some memory allocated to some pointers/data structures are not freed properly before the JNI function returns. There might be some other reasons too. 
Check if all memories are freed properly which were allocated before switching contexts.